# How to set Projectile project name as frame title

Tags: frames, projectile

I would like to have the Projectile project name as frame title and also have it updated when I switch between two different buffers in two different Projectile projects. I tried with the following:

```
(setq frame-title-format
      '("" (:eval projectile-project-name-function)))
```

This doesn't work at all. The frame title is blank with no text at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code works for me.

```
(setq frame-title-format
    '(""
      "%b"
      (:eval
       (let ((project-name (projectile-project-name)))
         (unless (string= "-" project-name)
           (format " in [%s]" project-name))))))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works just like I wanted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use this code

```el
;; Set my-projectile-project-name to projectile-project-name,
;; so that later I can also set projectile project name when in *Messages* buffer etc
(defun my-projectile-switch-project-action ()
  (set-frame-parameter nil 'my-projectile-project-name projectile-project-name)
  (projectile-run-eshell)
  (projectile-find-file))

(setq projectile-switch-project-action 'my-projectile-switch-project-action)

(setq frame-title-format
    '(""
      "%b"
      (:eval
       (let ((project-name (projectile-project-name)))
           (if (not (string= "-" project-name))
             (format " in [%s]" project-name)
             (format " in [%s]" (frame-parameter nil 'my-projectile-project-name)))))))
```

I've previously used https://github.com/john2x/nameframe.

It will switch to projectile project frame if there is already opened such.

It sets persistent projectile project name in frame title, but [its format is not customizable](https://github.com/john2x/nameframe/issues/6) and there appears [separate window with `*Messages*`](https://github.com/john2x/nameframe/issues/10). And if you close it, all emacs frames are closed.